# connect mysql database from smart gwt

Tags: java, mysql, smartgwt

can anybody know how to connect SmartGwt-EE with mysql database?

i refer so many links and examples there is no help for mysql connectivity all examples with hsql database.

i want to use SmartGwt DataSource to integrate with ui and database.

can anyone have good tutorial for SmartGWT and Mysql Connectivity.

please help me.

### Update 1

***I found the Solution.*** Below are some of links from where I found solution. just check it.

[link1](http://smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#sql_basic_connector), [link2](http://smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#sql_db_browser_wizard) , [link3](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/showcase/tools/adminConsole.jsp)

Comment: I found the Solution.   hear is some of links from where i found solution. just check it. http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#sql_basic_connector  , http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#sql_db_browser_wizard  ,  http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/showcase/tools/adminConsole.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I found the Solution.***

Below are some of links from where I found solution. just check it.

[link1](http://smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#sql_basic_connector), [link2](http://smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#sql_db_browser_wizard) , [link3](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/showcase/tools/adminConsole.jsp)